# jQuery needed for Bootstrap in React project

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am developing a React.js project where instead of using React-Bootstrap, I am loading the CSS of Bootstrap into my project. I am now needing to import the jQuery so that I can use dropdown menus etc.

Entry point file (index.js) - in the hope it would work

```
'use strict'
import React from 'react'
import { Route, Router, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from 'react-router'
import { render } from 'react-dom'

// Pages
import Main from './pages/main/main'
import Home from './pages/home/home'
import About from './pages/about/about'
window.jQuery = window.$ = require('jquery/dist/jquery.min')
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'

render((
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route name='home' path='/' component={Main}>
      <IndexRoute component={Home} />
      <Route name='about' path='about' component={About} />
    </Route>
  </Router>), document.getElementById('app'))
```

Webpack file

```
'use strict'
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './browser/index'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'js'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/public/js/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery'
    }),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: [ 'es2015', 'react' ]
        },
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'browser')
      },
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' },
      {test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file'},
      {test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/, loader: 'url?prefix=font/&limit=5000'},
      {test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream'},
      {test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'},
      { test: require.resolve('jquery'), loader: 'imports?jQuery=jquery' }
    ]
  }
}
```

The error appears in Chrome Dev tools: 'Bootstrap's Javascript requires jQuery'. I'm wondering whether perhaps I am missing something in terms on loaders in the webpack file, or need an import statement in the entry file?

Comment: Try moving  your jquery import in your webpack file above your babel-loader.

Comment: The error still remains sadly. In my package.json - "jquery": "^3.0.0" if that is any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please make sure you have installed 'imports-loader', (npm install --save imports-loader). And in module.exports try this:

```
{ test: /bootstrap.+\.(jsx|js)$/, loader: 'imports?jQuery=jquery,$=jquery,this=>window' }
```

The really nice post regarding it I've found here: http://reactkungfu.com/2015/10/integrating-jquery-chosen-with-webpack-using-imports-loader/

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately provided solution doesn't work for me. In the case above Bootstrap and jQuery are both installed as npm dependencies under node_modules directory? I'm using WebPack 2, so I have converted the loader element as follows:

```
{
        test: /bootstrap.+\.(jsx|js)$/,
        use: 'imports-loader?jQuery=jquery,$=jquery,this=>window',
        exclude: /node_modules/
}
```