# jQuery not working (ReactJS, Bootstrap, Webpack)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, webpack

Using a create-react-app ejected project.

I'm following this other stackoverflow answer: [Using Jquery and Bootstrap with Es6 Import for React App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40288268/using-jquery-and-bootstrap-with-es6-import-for-react-app)

The problem is that jQuery isn't working at all in in **production mode**, even tho Bootstrap doesn't throw the error that jQuery isn't available.

main.js:

```
// CSS
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './theme/css/style.css';
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';

// JS
import 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap';
```

element that uses bootstrap+jquery:

```
<li id="user-menu" class="dropdown menu-merge pull-right">
  <a aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span>User</span>
    <span class="caret ml10"></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu w225" role="menu">
    <li>
      <a href="/admin/instance">
        <span class="icon icon-Gear mr10"></span>
          Config
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

It simply won't open, unlike using webpack dev config, where it does.

- Webpack's production config file: https://pastebin.com/vb69MRug
- Webpack's development config file: https://pastebin.com/YwE7cuUf

What is going on?

Answer (score -1):

Shouldn't your jQuery import be:

`import $ from 'jquery';` instead of `import 'jquery'`

Also why not use [React-Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) instead? This doesn't seem worth the trouble.

Comment: No, using your way you're assigning all the jQuery functionality to $ var but only in the main.js file and bootstrap needs it as a global, that's why I'm using the ProvidePlugin in the Webpack configuration.

We're not using React-Bootstrap (yet) because the API isn't consistent yet and other team reasons.

Comment: have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37932454/jquery-needed-for-bootstrap-in-react-project